# How to find image path in c#?

Tags: c#, path, directory, filepath

I want to find image path but I didn't.

my image path : C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img
my image name : reset_password.jpg

I tried this : `string path2 = Path.GetFullPath("reset_password.jpg");` but it's wrong path `(output: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv)`

and tried this :

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string a = Path.Combine(path, "reset_password.jpg");

output : (C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\bin )
```

I think, output should be like this : `C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img`

one more thing : image path may not be same another computer so I think give a specific path is not right (for example : C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img )

```
X computer : C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img
Y computer : C:\Works\Web\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img
```

By the way, I am writing with c#.

How can I do ?
Any ideas please.

Comment: You can't just by passing the image name find its path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood the issue but an idea of how to find the same file on many systems is:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

This will give you the location of the folder that your running executable is in. The output is in the format of
"C:\Folder\Folder\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\".

So, you can put the image in the same folder as the .exe, add "imagefilename.type" and you should find it.

Please clarify if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks a lot ! @Julis A

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you your desired output

```
string folderPath = @"C:\Works\Web5.1.0\Src\Works.WebNext\Password\assets\img";
string imgFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "reset_password.jpg")
```

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` gives the path of the current working directory i.e. the path from where your executables are being run (in your case its 'bin' folder)

Comment: But image path may not be same another computer. Is it right to give a specific path ? @Amey Kamat

Comment: You can either pick the folder path using a key in your config(App.Config) or use a `Relative path` and keep the image in a folder which will be residing in your Release folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Web Applications.

```
string imagePath = "/Password/";  /* Your Image folder */
string path = Server.MapPath(@"ImagePath" + imagePath);
```

In Windows Application:

```
try
{
  System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"Your local Image directory inside bin/debug");

  FileInfo result = null;
  var list = directory.GetFiles(); // Stackoverflow Exception occurs here
  
  if (list.Count() > 0)
  {
    result = list.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
  }
                
  return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
```